# Jquery searching element in DOM after ajax loading

Tags: ajax, dom, onclick

How can I achieve something like this without on click method ? I load my view via Ajax and then I want use find method, but elements are invisable.

```
$('body).on('click', 'p', function() {
  do something
});
```

Notice that I don't want use find method immediately after ajax so something like this can't be my solution

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'url'
            }).done(function(data) {
                something
            });
```

Comment: The dom map are created at load time. But you should be able to extend functionality to childrens like $("#my_main_div").on("click",".sub_element",function .... If not, try a find-match, but they are more expensive

Comment: I mentioned that I don't want use click event, find also doesn't work

Comment: You need an event to use on delegate. Without delegate, the bubbling works only for wat it is allready created. Or you could „register” your elements in ajax.done(like push them in an array or something),  and then only acces them.

Comment: Delegate is deprecated, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but the same concept is used with parent.on(child selector):„delegate” on childrens that may not be created, but touched if are there at event propagation. Isn't easier to put elements in array at ajax creation time? Or parent.on('child_added', function(paint me)...